# Using a Base64 image Data URI as input to a POST

Tags: javascript, ajax, base64, blob, multipartform-data

I'm getting an image back from an API in Base64 Data URL format.  I need to use this as input to another API which is expecting a file in form data.  Here's the CURL example:

```
curl -X POST "<API URL>" -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data' -F "files=@/path/to/your/file.png"
```

I found a dataURItoBlob utility and I'm doing this:

```
imageBlob = dataURItoBlob(dataUrl);
var ajaxData = new FormData();
ajaxData.append('files', imageBlob);
```

Then I'm passing ajaxData as the data element for an ajax POST.  That API stores the file on Amazon and returns a URL.

The URL downloads a file called "blob" and if I rename this to "blob.png", I can see it's a valid image.  So one question is, how can I specify a name in the formdata so it has a proper extension?  And, is there something I'm doing wrong here that is not fully emulating what would normally be happening with a plain file upload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a third argument to the [append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) method which will be used as the file name

```
ajaxData.append('files', imageBlob, "image.png");
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah figured it out.  Had to convert the blob to a file first:

```
imageFile = new File([imageBlob], "image.png")
```

Comment: Use the third param, File constructor has less support.